# Applied to the lottery or for the lottery?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

Which preposition should I use in the following sentence:

> I applied ____ greencard lottery.

Would it be:

> I applied **for** the greencard lottery.

or

> I applied **to** the greencard lottery.

If both are fine, how would I decide which one to use?
If neither are fine, how should I convey the thought I am trying to convey?

Comment: Are you applying in order to get funding? - a job? Please explain.

Comment: I am describing an action I took in the past. Literally applying.

Comment: If the situation is that not all who validly try to enter the lottery even get their names entered into it, but some are rejected even before the drawing, then perhaps apply *for.* But if to put your name forward is more or less automatically to place it among the names from which winners will be selected by lottery, I would say you did not *apply* (for or to) but rather *entered* the lottery, which takes no preposition.

Comment: @BrianDonovan thanks. It is the case that some are rejected before the drawing.

Comment: Oh, I see. As a Brit, I didn't know what the Green Card Lottery was. I thought it was about winning cash like other lotteries.

Comment: It's [normally written as two words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diversity_Immigrant_Visa), but I can't see any reason why you shouldn't *apply **through** the Green Card Lottery* - or ***using***, or ***via***, or probably several other prepositions, since it's effectively a *scheme* (akin to would-be students in the UK who *apply through Clearing* for a university place). Cutting to the chase, it's all a matter of opinion.

Comment: This question should be asked on the english-learners site, Viktor.

Comment: Rather then "apply", people **register** to the green card lottery.

Comment: If you want to use _applied_ in connection with this lottery, you might use the phrasing "I applied for inclusion in the greencard lottery" or "I applied to have my name included in greencard lottery."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't apply for a lottery.  You're trying to combine "apply for" and "take part in".

What you want to say is "I applied for a green card by participating in the green card lottery." That is a bit wordy, so you might say "I participated in the green card lottery."

You could also say "I submitted my application and took part in the green card lottery."

Answer (score 4):

I think you really wanted to add an "a" and "in the". Like,

> I applied for a [green card](http://www.uscis.gov/greencard) in the [visa lottery](https://www.dvlottery.state.gov/ESC/%28S%28ffdzhyj1osh4anekssh1ipdp%29%29/default.aspx).

The green card is what you hope to receive, the visa lottery is how the green cards are allocated among applicants.

Comment: you know, i think it's "green card" (for example the film of that name) - it's not one word.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch green cards and visas are different things.  The grammar in your sentence is fine but the statement is not true.  Visas are permission to enter a country for a limited duration.  Green cards give unlimited access.  You can't get a green card from a visa lottery.  It's like saying "I won a car in the office cake lottery."

Comment: @michael_timofeev Actually, it refers to a [permanent resident](http://www.uscis.gov/greencard). The visa lottery is (one) method to become a **permanent resident**. [**Other Ways to Get a Green Card**](http://www.uscis.gov/green-card/other-ways-get-green-card) says (in part) *there are other ways a Green Card (permanent residence) can be obtained, such as the: Diversity Immigrant Visa Program (referred to by many as the 'Green Card Lottery')*.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it's referring to different steps in the process and trying to say a visa is the same thing as a green card.  You don't get a green card through a visa process and a green card is not a visa.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch it would be like saying "I applied for a driver's license in the airline pilot's lottery."

Comment: Hey michael -- bizarrely, the "green card lottery" is in fact officially called the "Diversity Immigrant Visa Program" (I'm fairly sure).  Note that US bureaucratic processes are arcane; your point is well-made, but it's quite possible that "green cards" {by the way - I'm sure anyway they are not actually called that} are, in fact, "visas" of some type officially.

Comment: @JoeBlow They are called green cards.  You first get a visa to come to the U.S. and then you apply for a green card.  The green card allows you to work in the US and come and go as you wish without a time limit.  Visas have time limits and are stamped in a passport.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I looked at the website you provided.  If I'm correct, you get a visa first through the lottery, then apply for the green card.  If you win the lottery you get a visa but not a green card.  Am I wrong in my understanding?  Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: Hey Michael - actually you usually / almost always have your spouse apply for one while you are still in the "other" country.  (For the record, I work very extensively with immigration attorneys.)  A "permanent resident card" is the actual name.  You can trivial find this information here.  http://www.uscis.gov/greencard.  (Your comment immediately above this one about "If I'm correct" is totally jumbled up; I don't even understand what you mean, sorry.)  The "lottery" is actually called the "Diversity Immigrant Visa Program" .. endless info here

Comment: BTW I just now (I feel like a smart-ass now :) ) by sheer coincidence had a top immigration attorney on the phone and I asked her if a green card "is a visa" and she ................. didn't know.  (Which is saying something!)  I would call it a "visa" because it is a, well, "permanent residence visa" (I"m not sure what other word you could use to describe it .. perhaps a "pass" or some such?  I guess the official name is a "card" -- I simply don't know.)